# How to make a shortcut key to screencapture a window and autosave the image?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

it is 2014 and a simple task like:

1. react to a shortcut-key
2. screenshot the currently active window
3. autosave the screenshot to a default location

seems to be way too fancy to get it for free on Mac with OS X 10.8.5

There are serevral seemingly able ways to do this, but one of these points won't work. The goal is to screencapture the visible part or the whole chrome-window on a mac using a keyboard shortcut and saving it automatically.

Mac Grab is able to do 1 & 3, but 2 you have to select the window and strike space every time

Chrome-Screencapture tools have a problem with NPAPI: http://awesomescreenshot.com/aws/Obstacles-to-Awesome-ness.html - so 3. is impossible

A Tool like SnapNGrab does only support shortcutkeys in a 6$ Pro Version (!!!) and does not seem to support autosave to default location

---

Would be happy about further ideas to solve this - a real solution must be able to do 1,2 and 3. OStriking the shortcutkey has to result in a screenshot.

---

and just to top it off - an old version of chrome is no solution eighter, as the web-store won't accept it - so there's the next obsticle ... what a crazy world

Comment: as stated, Cmd+Shift+4 does work, but you need to push space and select the window, which is not what I want - I want the active window to be selected automatical

Comment: Does this work? Post 3. http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=38482. I have SL and it doesn't work on SL - you can try on 10.8.5 though...

Comment: @shup looks promising, feels like IKEA "some assembly required", but I'll try that - thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is annoying but it should work. It will copy the image to clipboard. If it works, tell me and I will edit the code to save to a default location instead of to clipboard.